# Google Apps sending limit exceeded, but the activity report shows only 54 sent emails for the month

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

This has been happening on and off for a couple of months now. Basically the client keeps getting her account suspended for exceeding the daily email sending limit but she doesn't send anywhere near the required amount of email to hit the limit. We just ran an activity report through Google and that said that she'd only sent 54 emails for the month of January.

I thought she might have been hacked so we changed passwords. Also checked the login activity, but that only showed her home and office IP addresses (as well as mine since I'd logged in to troubleshoot). There are no weird emails in her sent folder, just emails she's sent.

I've just added an SPF record to see if that will help.

Is there anything else that I can do to find out why she keeps hitting this sending limit?

PS - it's a free Google Apps account so talking to their paid support isn't an option at this point.

Comment: You might get better results asking this on the [Google product forums](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/apps).

Answer (score 1):

If she is using Google Chrome, disable all her extensions and re-enable them one at a time until the problem returns.

Have seen a similar problem with "Enhancements for Gmail" extension. If you have this one, recommend you disable it first.